# How to make a timeseries plot of pandas dataframe with a groupby('user')?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
user date        amount 
1    2019-11-11  20
2    2019-11-12  40
2    2019-11-12  23
2    2019-11-13  10
3    2019-11-13  50
```

I've done some grooping and resampling stuff with it:

```
g = df.groupby('user')
g['amount'].resample('D').sum()
```

I got this:

```
user date
1    2019-11-11 20
     2019-11-12 0
     2019-11-13 0
2    2019-11-11 0
     2019-11-12 63
     2019-11-13 10
3    2019-11-11 0
     2019-11-12 0
     2019-11-13 50
```

How can I turn this into plot that looks something like this where each line is a user (this picture does not represent above mentioned numbers):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one liner, no need to do `.resample()`

```
df.groupby(['date','user']).sum()['amount'].unstack().fillna(0).plot()
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!